# Better approach for reading/writing files in python?

Tags: python, file-handling

Suppose I have a file (say `file1.txt`) with data around 3mb or more. If I want to write this data to a second file (say `file2.txt`), which one of the following approaches will be better?

Language used: Python 2.7.3

**Approach 1**:

```
file1_handler = file("file1.txt", 'r')
for lines in file1_handler:
    line = lines.strip()
    # Perform some operation
    file2_handler = file("file2.txt", 'a')
    file2_handler.write(line)
    file2_handler.write('\r\n')
    file2_handler.close()
file1_handler.close()
```

**Approach 2**:

```
file1_handler = file("file1.txt", 'r')
file2_handler = file("file2.txt", 'a')
for lines in file1_handler:
    line = lines.strip()
    # Perform some operation
    file2_handler.write(line)
    file2_handler.write('\r\n')
file2_handler.close()
file1_handler.close()
```

I think approach two will be better because you just have to open and close `file2.txt` once. What do you say?

Comment: Open a file with [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), not with [file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), it will close the files automatically for you:

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as in_file, open("file2.txt", 'a') as out_file:
    for lines in in_file:
        line = lines.strip()
        # Perform some operation
        out_file.write(line)
        out_file.write('\r\n')
```

Use `open` instead of `file`, `file` is deprecated.

Of course it's unreasonable to open file2 on every line of file1.

Comment: I was writing the same think :) @Hemant, look at: http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement

Comment: Regarding f2.write('\r\n'): in order to do this you need to open f2 as binary file (appending "b" to the flag).

Comment: oops! I thought open has been deprecated :p ( i din't read the documents properly)
so does the speed of writing increase? Because approach one was taking almost 2 hours for copying 1 MB of data.

Comment: @Francesco: can you please explain a bit on this binary file approach?

Comment: @Hemant: look at: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536545/how-to-write-unix-end-of-line-characters-in-windows-using-python
If you write "\n" without the binary mode, Python will use the more appropriate endline for your platform. If you want to use a particular endline, you should use the binary flag.

Comment: This is relevant only on windows. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written.

Comment: @Hemant: you could consider to implement a buffer in order to make a pair of big writes and not many little ones. You could just append your lines to a list and, when the list is quite big, write them all.

Comment: @Francesco: the reason of using '\r\n' is that I want to enter the next line from file1 to the next line of file2. does binary mode does this or simply keep '\r\n' as it is?

Comment: @Hemant: yes. \r\n is for Windows, on Linux/Mac you have \n. If you're on Linux and you want to write as Windows (for example), you have to use the binary mode and write \r\n.

Comment: @Francesco: I'll try to implement this buffer approach :)

Comment: Binary mode has no effect on Unix. It writes what it's told to write.

Comment: @Francesco: I din't get you.. your 'yes' is for which answer? converting to the newline or writing '\r\n' as it is?

Comment: Text mode on Windows converts `\r` and `\n` to `\r\n`. `\r\n` is left unchanged.

Comment: @PavelAnossov thank you for the information.
Hemant: PavelAnossov answered correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

I was recently doing something similar (if I understood you well). How about:

```
file = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'wt')

for line in file:
  newLine = line.strip()

  # You can do your operation here on newLine

  file2.write(newLine)
  file2.write('\r\n')

file.close()
file2.close()
```

This approach works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

My solution (derived from Pavel Anossov + buffering):

```
dim = 1000
buffer = []
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as in_file, open("file2.txt", 'a') as out_file:
    for i, lines in enumerate(in_file):
        line = lines.strip()
        # Perform some operation
        buffer.append(line)
        if i%dim == dim-1:
            for bline in buffer:
                out_file.write(bline)
                out_file.write('\r\n')
            buffer = []
```

Pavel Anossov gave the right solution first: this is just a suggestion ;)
Probably it exists a more elegant way to implement this function. If anyone knows it, please tell us.

Comment: @ Francesco: Hey thanks for this answer :) but I am not much familiar with enumerate method. Can please explain me benefits of using enumerate?

Comment: @Hemant: enumerate is useful :) Look here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: @ Francesco: thanks for the doc. now i understand your example more clearly. :)