# Ubuntu shell script: Using >> the output txt file is not opening

Tags: python-2.7, shell, ubuntu, sh

I using the following `python` script to create a `shell` script:

```
with open("decode_JOURNAL2017.sh", "a") as myfile:
    levels_no = 16
    #myfile.write("#!/bin/bash\n")
    for x in range(0, levels_no):
        myfile.write("/home/zinonas/SHM-12.3/bin/TAppDecoderStatic -b /home/zinonas/str/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P.bin -olsidx "+str(x)+" -o"+str(x)+" /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_"+str(x)+"_dec.yuv >> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_"+str(x)+"_dec.txt\n")
```

Then I transfer the following created script to an `ubuntu` server:

```
/home/zinonas/SHM-12.3/bin/TAppDecoderStatic -b /home/zinonas/str/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P.bin -olsidx 0 -o0 /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_0_dec.yuv >> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_0_dec.txt
/home/zinonas/SHM-12.3/bin/TAppDecoderStatic -b /home/zinonas/str/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P.bin -olsidx 1 -o1 /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_1_dec.yuv >> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_1_dec.txt
/home/zinonas/SHM-12.3/bin/TAppDecoderStatic -b /home/zinonas/str/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P.bin -olsidx 2 -o2 /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_2_dec.yuv >> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_2_dec.txt
```

When I run it, the txt files are created but when I double click to one to open it I get this message:

```
Can't create file 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\scp43940\home\zinonas\decode\pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_0_dec.txt
'.
System Error.  Code: 123.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I can't even transfer this txt file to my windows desktop via `winscp`.

The `yuv` files are working properly!

**EDIT**: When I copy/paste the content of the `shell` script to the terminal, the txt files are working properly.
**EDIT 2**: When I rename the file and remove `txt` and add it again, the file opens properly...

Do you know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @molbdnilo When I try to open other txt files from the server, `winscp` opens them correctly. I believe that the error might be in the `shell` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

While creating the `shell` script, next to the name of the txt file I had:

```
...
>> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_"+str(x)+"_dec.txt\n")
```

so the new line character `\n` want next to `txt`. That was the problem. I added a new space between them and the problem solved!

My new code now reads:

```
...
>> /home/zinonas/decode/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_"+str(x)+"_dec.txt \n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have Windows line endings in the script file – at least that's why I get from the error message if you pasted it correctly.

Run `dos2unix scriptFilename.sh` or `sed -i 's/\r//' scriptFilename.sh` to remove the Windows line endings from the script.

---

For Python scripting refer to this Question&Answer: [How to write Unix end of line characters in Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536545/how-to-write-unix-end-of-line-characters-in-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a "rogue" CR at the end of the file name?